# Join the same table duplicate rows

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I'm trying to join the same table in a query, but I get duplicate rows.

What i want to get is a column with the total sum of invoices for the year, and a column for each Trimester for each client.

Here is a simplified version of the query:

```
select client.name, sum(total.totdoc) as TOTAL, sum(t1.totdoc) as T1 
from client
     join invoices total
          on total.idclient=client.idclient
     join invoices t1
          on t1.idclient=total.idclient
where t1.date between '01/01/2016' and '30/03/2016'
      and total.date between '01/01/2016' and '31/12/2016'
group by client.name
having sum(total.income) > '1000'
```

Example data (clients is just idclient and name):

```
Invoices table
  Idclient       totdoc     date
     1           123.56  '01/02/2016'
     1          1,258.61 '05/05/2016'
     2          2,557.32 '07/03/2016'
     3          123.56   '30/11/2016'
```

The outpot should then be:

```
client name       Total         T1
    A            1382.17      123.56
    B           2,557.32     2,557.32
```

When I check manually for one of them, the result should be around 3.000 and I'm getting around 81.000

I tried with `sum(distinct total.totdoc)` and it works on some (the ones with different totals), but the ones that are repeated get lost.

Again, this is a simplified example, so if anything is unclear, please ask.

Thanks!

Comment: Think you lack ... group by client.name

Comment: There is a missing quote here: `where t1.date between '01/01/2016' and 30/06/2016'`

Comment: can you provide some sample data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just want conditional aggregation.  Something like this:

```
select c.name, sum(i.totdoc) as total,
       sum(case when month(date) in (1, 2, 3) then i.totdoc end) as q1,
       sum(case when month(date) in (4, 5, 6) then i.totdoc end) as q2,
       sum(case when month(date) in (7, 8, 9) then i.totdoc end) as q3,
       sum(case when month(date) in (10, 11, 12) then i.totdoc end) as q4
from client c join
     invoices i
     on i.idclient = c.idclient
where i.date >= '2016-01-01' and i.date < '2017-01-01'
group by c.name
having sum(i.income) > 1000;
```

Comment: This works great! I didn't know you could use conditionals like this in SQL.
Thanks, you are a lifesaver! (just as a sidenote, on the having clause you have to sum i.totdoc :P)

Answer (score 0):

I Think you should not join with invoices T1, you are getting this duplicate records because of this, Only one join is enough. if you see the query than the row which satisfies the first join is selected and then the same row is get selected by the second join. I think you need to separate the queries for the  sum of invoices for the year and Trimester for each client.

Like

```
select client.name, sum(total.totdoc) as TOTAL, sum(total.totdoc) as T1 
 from client
 join invoices total
      on total.idclient=client.idclient
 where total.date between '01/01/2016' and '30/06/2016'
  and total.date between '01/01/2016' and '31/12/2016'
```

Comment: I don't see anything different from the example I provided

Comment: Now Try hope this will make some difference

Comment: T1 is not declared, so it can't find t1.date or t1.totdoc

Comment: Try now actually i just forgott to remove t1

Comment: this returns both columns with the same value.